# Getting the value after an event is fired in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am relatively new to JavaFX, and I've been searching the forums for a few days, but I haven't found a clear solution to my problem. Please consider below code:

```
    public class MeasureController implements Initializable {

    double retdx;

    public void dxCalc() {
    double dx = 5;
    retdx = dx;
    }

    @FXML
    void fireMeasure(ActionEvent event) {
    dxCalc();   
    }
}
```

As you can see above, I have this class called *MeasureController*, and I have a scene node (button) that when a user press, it will call the method inside the *fireMeasure* event. My problem is I cannot get the value *double retdx* or *double dx* and pass it to another class controller. I have tried with the following code, but none seems to work:

```
public class DataController extends Thread implements Initializable {

FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new 
FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Measure.fxml"));
Parent offsetScene = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
Stage offsetStage = new Stage();
offsetStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
offsetStage.setScene(new Scene(offsetScene));
offsetStage.show();

MeasureController ofX = new MeasureController();        
double setX = ofX.retdx;    
}
```

or:

```
public class DataController extends Thread implements Initializable {

FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new 
FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Measure.fxml"));
Parent offsetScene = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
Stage offsetStage = new Stage();
offsetStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
offsetStage.setScene(new Scene(offsetScene));
offsetStage.show();

MeasureController ofX = new MeasureController();        
double setX = ofX.dxCalc();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MeasureController ofX = new MeasureController();
double setX = ofX.dxCalc();
```

This is not how you should get the controller instance. The instance you're creating here is not used with a fxml. Instead you should use `FXMLLoader.getController` to access the controller instance created while loading the fxml:

```
MeasureController ofX = load.getController();
```

Note that the statement

```
double setX = ofX.dxCalc();
```

is executed before the user has a chance to interact with the new window. You should allow `DataController` to listen to events that are the result of the user interacting with the GUI.
If you're only interested to be notified when the value changes, you could e.g. add a `DoubleProperty` to `MeasureController`:

```
public class MeasureController implements Initializable {

    private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper retdx = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper();

    public double getRetdx() {
        return retdx.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty retdxProperty() {
        retrun retdx.getReadOnlyProperty​();
    }

    private void dxCalc() { // should there be access to this method from outside this class? imho no -> private
        double dx = 5;
        retdx.set(dx);
    }

    @FXML
    void fireMeasure(ActionEvent event) {
        dxCalc();   
    }
}
```

```
offsetStage.show();

MeasureController ofX = loader.getController();
ofX.retdxProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    // do something on value change
    System.out.println(newValue);
});
```

---

If you're interested in receiving the event regardless of a change of the value, you could add your own `addListener` (or similarly named) method to `MeasureController`, e.g. one that you can pass `Consumer<Double>` to which stores the consumers in a list and on calling `dxCalc` it passes `dx` to all `Consumer`s in the list...

Comment: OMG. Thanks, this is what I've been looking for all this time. Your solution solves my problem. Now I only needed to change the `show()` to `showAndWait()` so the user can put the parameters required before the proceeding methods start.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see how you define your `dxCalc()` method with a `void` keyword?  The `void` keyword tells Java that you want the method to perform something, but you don't need anything back from it.

The `void` is what's called the "return type," or the type of value that the method returns.  `void` essentially means "nothing."

Now, take the following example:

```
String getName() {
    return "Rob";
}
```

This is also a method, but you see how `void` has been changed to `String`?  This means whenever this method is called, you will get a `String` in return.  The `return` keyword within the method is what actually tells Java what value to return.

So, given the above example, if we were to use the following code:

```
System.out.println(getName());
```

The output would be:

```
robert
```

In your case, you are calling the `dxCalc()` method, but since the method doesn't return a value, you cannot do anything with the result of the calculation.

If you were to change the method to the following:

```
double dxCalc() {
  double dx = 5.0;
  return dx;
}
```

You are telling Java that when the `dxCalc()` method is called, send back a `double` value.  So in your `fireMeasure()` method from your FXML button, you can use the value like this, for example:

```
@FXML
void fireMeasure() {
  System.out.println(dxCalc());
}
```

The `dxCalc()` method call is replaced with the returned value from the method so `5.0` gets printed.

Comment: I have also tried your suggestion above. The solution works fine if the `dxCalc()` is just called within the `fireMeasure()`, which means in the same controller. My problem is after the `fireMeasure()` button is clicked, I cannot get the value of `return dx;` from another controller, which is in my code above the `DataController ` class.

Comment: If you call `ofx.dxCalc()`, with parentheses, after adding the return type, from `DataController`, it should work just fine. If you are getting an error message, you should add that to your question. Otherwise, just saying "cannot get value" is impossible for us to solve.

Comment: Edited: Thanks for your answer. I instantiated the object in another class like so: `MeasureController ofX = new MeasureController();
      
double offsetX = ofX.dxCalc();
System.out.println(offsetX);` but the output is 0 instead of 5. There's no error in the output window so I don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: And unless your `dxCalc()` method provides a `return` statement, the value will always be 0.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your answer as it works out for the code I stated above. I will try to reconstruct my question with your comment above in mind.

Comment: I re-accepted another answer as the solution provided suits my needs best. But the solution provided by Zephyr still works for the most situation.